# npx create-react-app is using wrong node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm

I have node installed through `nvm` and I'm currently using v10.16.3. This lives in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm`. When I try running `npx create-react-app new-app`, it tells me I'm using npm v3.5.3, and subsequently fails with a MODULE_NOT_FOUND involving 'internal/util/types'. I suspect this is because it's trying to use the bloody old npm version.

The frustrating thing is, when I run `npm -v` it tells me `v6.9.0`. In that nvm folder, in `node_modules` folder, I see an npm folder whose package json indeed tells me it's `v6.9.0`. However, in another part of my pc, I have a massive node_modules folder (`C:\Users\User\node_modules`), and this is where it's somehow trying to access npm. This is where the old v3.5.3 lives. I've checked my PATH vars, nothing is pointing here. Why the heck is nvm deciding not to use the npm that lives in its own damn folder?

I tried deleting the old npm in the wrong folder, but that clearly didn't fix anything.